# Could not access the function one activity from another activity in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created an image view for picking instant camera.It is delcared in the second activity. Then i called a function in first activity. But i am getting these error. Please give a solution. Here i shared my code. Thanks in andvance.

```
 First Activity
 --------------
 private val createHomeworkActivity = CreateHomeworkActivity()

  when (v?.id){
        R.id.take_a_photo  -> createHomeworkActivity.tapOnCamera()
    }

 Second Activity
 ---------------

fun tapOnCamera(){

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), RC_PERM_PICK_IMAGE)
    } else {
        
        openCamera()
       
        iv_multi_image_layout.visibility=View.VISIBLE

    }
```

}

This is the error...
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.checkPermission(ContextWrapper.java:743)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ContextCompat.java:544)

Comment: You can't create instance of an `Activity`.

Comment: Could you please suggest a solution

Comment: Check this [thread](https://medium.com/@bionicwan/android-how-to-take-a-photo-using-kotlin-6ce7f0dee9c8)

Comment: Ok let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your function to another class. Not use in your activity.

You are just create a instance of SecondActivity. But secondActivity doesn't any context yet. So it throws null pointer exception. Which error in below

> android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)'
> on a null object reference at

You can create a new class. You can make a static class. And create a function ; input parameters (context:Context) and returns boolean(permisson granted or not granted). This method just responsible of permission. Do not use for **openCamera()**